# create bmp image of sine wave

Tags: matlab, bitmap, trigonometry

I would like to create bitmap for any sine grating. How could I accomplish this.

I am doing that:

```
n = 64;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,n));

sinewave2D=sin(5*X);

plot(sinewave2D(1,:)) 

imagesc(sinewave2D) 
imwrite(sinewave2D,'sine.bmp') 
imshow('sine.bmp')
```

But "sinewave2D" has negative values and bmp accepts values between 0-255 so how can I accomplish that and have my gratings that I need.

Comment: As you tagged Matlab [look here](http://matlabgeeks.com/tutorial/plots/) - it tells you how to plot and save.

Comment: Yes but I want it to be a bitmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though the problem is how to deal with negative numbers.

As the programmer, this is your choice!

One method would be to normalize your sine wave to fit in the output range, as follows:

```
% shift digital counts so the minimum is at zero
sinewave2D = sinewave2D - min(sinewave2D(:);

% scale digital counts so the maximum is at 255
sinewave2D = sinewave2D / max(sinewave2D(:) * 255;

% then, write the image
imwrite(uint8(sindwave2D), 'sine.bmp');
```

The problem with this method, of course, is if the dynamic range of the sine wave changes, these changes will not be reflected in the output image! It also centers zero at a nonzero digital count, so zero will appear gray in the bitmap.

Comment: I accept this answer and it nice one and very nice but one small mistake that when you shit it you have to put max instead of min because the shifting was to the negative values in the case you said. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: Ah, yeah, should have technically been a subtraction of the minimum. I've edited to reflect this.